# MIna Operation timed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, mina

Someone is getting the same issue trying to deploy using mina on EC2?

> ssh: connect to host 100.10.10.10 port 22: Operation timed out
>
> ! Command failed. Failed with status 1 (255)

**my domain configuration:**

```
set :domain, '100.10.10.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

use domain name instead of ip.

Comment: It might help if you provide an example of what you're talking about. Your answer is very short

Comment: an example would be nice

Comment: If you run into this, carefully check if you can ssh to user@domain, use copy and paste to fetch username and domain (ip) from your deploy.rb